# Holding down a key freezes a video pipeline in OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have a program, which gets video from industrial camera. I use OpenCV in order to display video and do some image analysing. I have several circles displayed on an image and there's a possibility to move them with keyboard. And when I press down a keyboard button and hold it, image acquisition freezes, but moving of a circle still happens (you can see this by unpressing the keyboard button and the circle moved).
Here is a simplified example:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2


WINDOW_NAME = 'program'
cv2.namedWindow(WINDOW_NAME, cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv2.setWindowProperty(WINDOW_NAME, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,
                      cv2.WINDOW_GUI_EXPANDED)

while True:
    # Simplified image acquisition.
    frame = (np.random.rand(1080, 1920, 3)*255).astype(np.uint8)

    cv2.imshow(WINDOW_NAME, frame)

    pressed_key_code = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if pressed_key_code == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
    # Simplified action on key press.
    elif pressed_key_code == ord('p'):
        print('moving action')
```

In this example if one presses and holds `p` the image acquisition stops, but one can see prints still happening.

I tried using different functions for waiting key: `cv2.pollKey()`, `cv2.waitKeyEx()`. I used different waiting time. Also after researching the problem, I've found some suggestions on using several `cv2.waitKey()` functions simultaneously.

I expect to see action not freezing image acquisition. What can I do?

---

OpenCV version: 4.7.0
Platform: Windows 10.0.17763 AMD64
HighGUI backend: WIN32UI

Comment: What platform, what OpenCV version, what HighGUI backend is it using?

Comment: OpenCV version: 4.7.0;
Platform: Windows 10.0.17763 AMD64;
HighGUI backend: WIN32UI.

Comment: OK, I can reproduce. It doesn't seem that "freezing image acquisition" is the case here -- in order for the text to be displayed multiple times, the whole `while` loop has to iterate multiple times, so new frame is generated every iteration. It's more like the paint events don't get to happen. (I have a faint recollection that Windows only generates WM_PAINT messages when there are no other messages in the message queue -- the constant stream of keypress events might be preventing that from happening)

Comment: One workaround that seems to mitigate the problem... instead of a `waitKey`, run `pollKey` in its own loop handling keypresses, until it returns -1. At that point there are no key events pending, and it seems to repaint. Like this: https://pastebin.com/6yNR2gxa

Comment: I've noticed this behavior on Win32 before. it appears that key events cause the event processing to end right away and don't give the GUI a chance to redraw. or something like that. in my investigation I tried to separate the message stream into GUI and input events and handle GUI events first... didn't get far, outcome unclear. **there should be a solution in principle.** -- **do not** run GUI calls in multiple threads. the GUI stuff is not generally thread-safe. it may work, or not. some gui backends even throw a fit if you call any GUI stuff from any thread that isn't the main thread.

Comment: Thank you, Dan Mašek, your workaround with second loop helped.